# Getting data from dynamically generated element at the click of a button in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am trying to retrieve data from a dynamically created `element` at the click of a button.

The script generating the element is:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        var dropdownid = $(this).data('value');
        var surname=$(this).data('surname');
        var middlename=$(this).data('middlename');
        var firstname=$(this).data('firstname');
        var attendees=$(this).data('attendees');

        $('.attendees').append('<div class='+dropdownid+'>'+firstname+' '+middlename+' '+surname+'</div>'+'<button class='+dropdownid+' id=btn-deleteattendee data-id='+dropdownid+' class=remove>X</button>');
    });
```

The script to retrieve the data upon a button click is:

```
$(document).on('click','#btn-createclass',function(){
        $('.attendees').each(function(result){
            console.log('attendees: ',result)
        });
```

However the console is printing this:

```
attendees: undefined
```

I have also tried this:

```
$('.attendees').on('click','#btn-createclass',function(event){
        console.log('createclass button clicked');
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.attendees').each(function(event){
            console.log('result ',$(this).data('id'));
        });
```

but that isn't working either. 
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you're using [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) correctly?

Comment: did you use `this.id`?

Comment: Did u see the 'createclass button clicked'?

Comment: It is not an answer, but, probably, you have another big problem. As I understand, you have more than one `attendee` generated. Then, you have a lot of buttons with id `btn-deleteattendee`. If yes, then it is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the button elements in `attendees` element which has the `data-id` attribute.

You are trying to get the `data-id` value from the `attendees` element, which does not have that value

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  var dropdownid = $(this).data('value');
  var surname = $(this).data('surname');
  var middlename = $(this).data('middlename');
  var firstname = $(this).data('firstname');
  var attendees = $(this).data('attendees');

  $('.attendees').append('<div class=' + dropdownid + '>' + firstname + ' ' + middlename + ' ' + surname + '</div>' + '<button class=' + dropdownid + ' id=btn-deleteattendee data-id=' + dropdownid + ' class=remove>X</button>');
});


$(document).on('click', '#btn-createclass', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.attendees [data-id]').each(function(event) {
    console.log('result', $(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a data-value="1" data-surname="s1" data-middlename="m1" data-firstname="f1" data-attendees="a1">1</a></li>
  <li><a data-value="2" data-surname="s2" data-middlename="m2" data-firstname="f2" data-attendees="a2">2</a></li>
  <li><a data-value="3" data-surname="s3" data-middlename="m3" data-firstname="f3" data-attendees="a3">3</a></li>
  <li><a data-value="4" data-surname="s4" data-middlename="m4" data-firstname="f4" data-attendees="a4">4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="attendees"></div>
<button id="btn-createclass">Create</button>
```

Comment: This worked! And thanks very much for pointing out that my element didn't have any data in it.